# Invoke multiple service operations at the same time

Tags: rest, http

Under the context of service based architecture, and if Restful HTTP web API is used to invoke a service, and if this service contains a number of different service operations, the question is that if it is possible, for the service consumer to invoke the service, with invoking more than one services operations at one request.

If it is possible, is there any restriction on the different services operation, e.g. both service operations need have the same service operation semantics, such as Request / response, or subscribe /notify?

If there is no such restriction, then how to map these service operations into HTTP method?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Frank